# Xamarin.Forms get pixel where clicked on Image

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm hoping there is a cross platform way to do this. I need to know the color pixel in an image a user clicked on. I only need to know whether or not it's transparent.

I see there's a Bitmap class in Mono.Android but then I need some way to do this in iOS.

Comment: You would have to do this with a custom renderer.

Comment: I ended up using SkiaSharp